# Thoughts on my neologism? Is it new?

Tags: neologisms, animacy

Anthropomorphize according to thesaurus.com has no synonyms and no antonyms. I've come up with the verb 'inanimate'.

Ex: Historians, usually of a left wing persuasion, have a marked tendency to rely on structural explanation. Much as myth anthropomorphizes nature, this brand of history inanimates man.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, there were two verbs spelled that way in the 1600s, although they are now obsolete. Etymologically, one came from the Latin *inanimāre* and had two meanings: "to infuse life into" and "to encourage". The other one (marked as "rare") came from the adjective inanimate and meant "to deprive of life."

In other words, it's an autoantonym, so I'd suggest avoiding it. Consider using "animate" instead.

Here's an example of the "to infuse life into" sense in action:

> God inanimates euery State with one power, as euery man with one soule.
>   <sub>[Pseudo-martyr](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A20647.0001.001/1:7?rgn=div1;view=fulltext), 1610</sub>

Answer (score 0):

A perfectly good antonym of anthropomorph already exists: zoomorph. However I don't sense you're wanting an antonym of anthropomorphic here, you're wanting  something like 'dehumanises' -?
As Laurel says, to me inanimate as a verb has a sense of inserting animation, as inseminate means inserting seed.